# want to send the streaming result in to the spring shell

Tags: spring, spring-shell

I am using spring shell framework for my cli. I have written some commands where it will display the results once the command is executed in my java application.

```
@CliCommand(value = "add jar", help = "adds a jar resource")
public String addJar(
    @CliOption(key = {"", "param"}, mandatory = true, help = "path to jar")          String path) {
    // code
    return result.getMessage();
}
```

The above command tries to add the jar and return the result to spring shell once the execution of command completes.
Right now, I am able to send the final result status to the spring shell. I wanted to send the execution status as well to the spring shell while executing.

My use case is: Is there any way to send periodic updates to the spring shell while command is running instead of sending whole result at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you please inside your command method, including writing to System.out (which will be emitted to the user).
So, for your particular use case, periodically poll the status of your execution and emit a message (maybe even using ANSI codes to overwrite the previous position, or display a progress bar with `print()` instead of `println()`, *etc.*)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. system.print  and println both works fine but my application uses log.info inside methods. I wanted to publish those data to cli not sysouts.

Comment: This should work too, assuming the logging framework is correctly configured to emit to standard out

Answer (score 0):

You can either append you logger to console.
If you want only your log.info to appear, you can configure it in you logging configuration.
For example in logback:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
      <level>INFO</level>
      <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
      <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>
        %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{30} - %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <!-- this is your normal logger -->
  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" /> 
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Or if you want to show the user messages about the status and not things you put to log. there is an method in abstract shell for displaying messages to the user.

```
@Autowired
private JLineShellComponent shell;

@CliCommand(value = "check", help = "just show messages")
public void check(){
    shell.flash(java.util.logging.Level.ALL, "initializing ", "id");
    init();
    shell.flash(java.util.logging.Level.ALL, "running", "id");
    run();
    shell.flash(java.util.logging.Level.ALL, "finished", "id");
    stop();
}
```